# Finding specific folder within path, and add altered version to the %PATH%

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line-interface, path-variables

I'm looking to find path with `client_1` string, replace `client_1` part with `client_1\bin`, and `set PATH=%PATH%;%newpath%`.

I've tried

```bash
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set newpath=
for %%a in ("%path:;=";"%") do (
    rem @echo %%~a
    if [%newpath%]==[] (
        echo %%~a | findstr /I /C:"client_1" >nul
        if not errorlevel 1 (
            set newpath=%%~a
            set newpath=!newpath:client_1\bin=client_1!
        )
    )
)

set PATH=%PATH%;%newpath%
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Variables are not behaving as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected) Specifically, since you're setting and using a variable inside of the same set of parentheses, you need to add `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` to the top of your script and use `!newpath:client_1\bin=client_1!` instead of `%newpath:client_1\bin=client_1%`.

Comment: @SomethingDark no, it's still failing

Comment: Could you elaborate on how it's failing? Is the variable not getting created at all?

Comment: @SomethingDark substitution wasn't working as expected.

Comment: Could you please explain what you're seeing and what you're expecting to see? I'd expect someone with 50k rep to know better than to respond with "it isn't working" when asked for elaboration.

Comment: Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Substitution part was also wrong beside missing `EnableDelayedExpansion`, and condition around newpath var also needed to use `!` instead of `%`.

```bash
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set newpath=
for %%a in ("%path:;=";"%") do (
    rem @echo %%~a
    if [!newpath!]==[] (
        echo %%~a | findstr /I /C:"client_1" >nul
        if not errorlevel 1 (
            set newpath=%%~a
            set newpath=!newpath:client_1=client_1\bin!
        )
    )
)

set PATH=%PATH%;%newpath%
```